# Google Maps SDK for Android - Add marker to street view

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm looking for a way to add Markers to a StreetViewPanorama using the Google Maps SDK for Android.  I found a way to do this using the SDK for iOS. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/streetview (bottom of page), but cannot find any documentation or sample code that does this on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Android Google maps API v2 can´t add markers, this option is only available for iOS.

`Markers within Street View` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/streetview#markers_within_street_view

one option would be using `Google Maps JavaScript API` inside a `WebView`.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays

Comment: I've been through that page a bunch of times.  No information on how to add markers to steetview.

Comment: Ok, I have a requirement for a project with this and now I have realized that this is currently available for iOS...  :(